# No consigo esconder div con jQuery

Tags: jquery

No consigo que al pulsar sobre un `label`, a través de jQuery un div desaparezca. Estoy la parte de HTML es esta:

```js
$(document).ready(main);

function main(){

$('#label_cookies').click(function(){
    document.getElementById('caja_cookies').style.display='none';
});
}
```

```html
<div id="caja_cookies">
  <p>Utilizamos "cookies" para ofrecerte una mejor experiencia de servicio. Al navegar o utilizar nuestros servicios, aceptas el uso que hacemos de las "cookies".</p>
  <div style="width:auto;margin-top:10px;">
    <input type="checkbox" name="checkbox" id="cookies_aceptar" value="value">
    <label id="label_cookies" for="cookies_aceptar">Aceptar</label>
    <a href="#">Más información</a>
  </div>

</div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

no hagas eso

```
$('#label_cookies').click(function(){
document.getElementById('caja_cookies').style.display='none';
```

});

trata esto

```
    $('#label_cookies').click(function(){
$(#caja_cookies).hide(600);
});
```

- el numero 600 da el efecto de ocultado lento
- hide es la funcion de ocultado en jquery

tambien puedes hacerlo con javascript

```
  function ocultar(){
      $(#caja_cookies).hide(600);
}
```

al formulario le agregue un `onclick='ocultar()'` que es el llamado de la funcion para disparar el ocultado

```
    <div id="caja_cookies">
  <p>Utilizamos "cookies" para ofrecerte una mejor experiencia de servicio. Al navegar o utilizar nuestros servicios, aceptas el uso que hacemos de las "cookies".</p>
```

```js
function ocultar(){
  $('#ocultardiv').hide(600);
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id='ocultardiv'>
     <div style="width:auto;margin-top:10px;">
        <input type="checkbox" name="checkbox" id="cookies_aceptar" value="value" onclick='ocultar()'>
        <label id="label_cookies" for="cookies_aceptar" >Aceptar</label>
        <a href="#">Más información</a>
      </div>

</div>
```

Aquí te dejo ya funcionando el ejemplo

Comment: He intentado la primera y no hace nada. Con la segunda opción me sale un error que no sé el motivo por el que me está saliendo: `Uncaught ReferenceError: ocultar is not defined
    at HTMLLabelElement.onclick`

Comment: Me sigue apareciendo el mismo error.

Comment: Hola de nuevo, no te funciona por que el onclick lo estas poniendo en el label, trata de ponerlo en el input como esta el código del ejemplo, puedes ejecutar el código del ejemplo que te puse para probar el funcionamiento

Answer (score 0):

Tu código está bien, tal vez solo te está faltando incluir la librería `jQuery` (verifica que versión deseas utilizar):

```
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Aquí el código funcionando:

```js
$(document).ready(main);

function main(){
  $('#label_cookies').click(function(){
      document.getElementById('caja_cookies').style.display='none';
  });
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div id="caja_cookies">
  <p>Utilizamos "cookies" para ofrecerte una mejor experiencia de servicio. Al navegar o utilizar nuestros servicios, aceptas el uso que hacemos de las "cookies".</p>
  <div style="width:auto;margin-top:10px;">
    <input type="checkbox" name="checkbox" id="cookies_aceptar" value="value">
    <label id="label_cookies" for="cookies_aceptar">Aceptar</label>
    <a href="#">Más información</a>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: No puede ser, es algo que estoy incluyendo a una web ya creada que tiene JS y jQuery funcionando. Veo que os funciona, pero a mi hay algo que me está impidiendo que se ejecute...y no sé qué me quiere decir este error: `Uncaught ReferenceError: ocultar is not defined
    at HTMLLabelElement.onclick`

Comment: Estás definiendo tu código javascript en el mismo archivo que el HTML o en un archivo separado?

Comment: Lo he intentado de 3 formas distintas. En fichero separado, abajo del todo (donde tengo otros scripts) y a la altura del header, y ninguna me funciona.

Comment: qué error te da con el código de esta respuesta?, ya que el error que mencionas `Uncaught ReferenceError: ocultar is not defined at HTMLLabelElement.onclick ` hace referencia a `ocultar`, lo cual no está en esta respuesta ni en tu pregunta

Comment: Estoy probando con otra opción que ha dado el usuario @gama984. En vez de usar jQuery usando javascript, y añadiendo al elemento `<label>` el evento `onclick="ocultar()"`.

Comment: Si lo hago de esta forma no me sale ningún error, pero es que tampoco hace nada. El div no desaparece.

Comment: es raro que no te funcione de esta manera, no tengo idea de por qué podría estar fallando, ya que aquí funciona. Respecto al otro error tal vez esta respuesta te pueda ayudar https://stackoverflow.com/a/17378538

Comment: Me he vuelto loco hasta darme cuenta que algo está pasando con Google Chrome. Aún borrando el fichero entero de JS que tenía me seguía cargando las cosas (salvo que borrase directamente el enlace del HTML). He probado con Firefox y me funciona. No sé si puede haber algún problema al subirlo a la web.